# webbrowser documentcompleted event with Dynamic Javascript sites

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I making a C# application which uses the webbrowser control to get content from a website.  The website uses text/x-handlebars-template javascript templates to load dynamic content.  Usually the page will say "Loading results ...".  That will trigger DocumentCompleted event.  After that, the page will "load" but no further triggers.  Is there a way to detect when the page is all the way loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up just polling the page for cues that it is done.  It's not the most elegant way but it seems to be working.